# What if someone anonymously confesses their sins indirectly

Tags: sin

Assalamu alaikum.

So let’s say that someone has a sinful habit and goes to a social media platform (Stackexchange, Reddit, etc.) and asks for help on  how to stop that habit. They indirectly confess their sins by admitting they have a sinful habit and they ask for help. They use a pseudonym/username that completely hides their identity. This person also does not know they are committing a sin at the time of posting.

I hear that confessing/exposing your sins is very bad and everyone can be excused except for those who publicly confess their sins. Does this person fall under that category?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Posting in such cases can hardly be regarded as exposing a sin. Exposing a sin requires at least that one tells people about it, who know you, and to tell it without being ashamed or in order to seek help, but being proud for this misdeed or seeking admiration for it. So if a person does so annonymously and with the intention of seeking help or advise this is not the case. Else how would one get fatwa or a legal verdict if people keep hiding such things.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Question, would the same rules apply if someone were to write about their sins online as a teaching intention to educate people why they shouldn't do this so others can benefit/learn from their lesson, would that also be okay?

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile If you have a question don't ask in comments.

Comment: @Medi1Saif It's literally on the same topic? There's not point starting a new thread when a similar question to it (this one) has already been discussed.